# ImageJ get value from an array

Tags: arrays, macros, matching, imagej

I am trying to match image files to a specific row in an array. 
In a first step I am selecting a folder that contain the tif files.
Then I am selecting a csv file with the information I would like to use.
I am opening each image one after the other. For an opened image I would like to retrieve the values from the line that correspond to the image name in the csv file. The header of the CSV file is FileName, XValue, YValue.

Here's my code so far... Any help would be appreciated.

```bs
// Make a pop up to select the input directory
InputDirPath=getDirectory("Select Input directory");

// Get the list of files in the input input directory selected above as an array
InputFileList=getFileList(InputDirPath);

 // Defines cell separator and line separator
CellSeparator=",";
LineSeparator="\n";

// open the csv file as a string
FileCCValuesPath=File.openDialog("Select the file containing the coordinates");
FileCCValuesString=File.openAsString(FileCCValuesPath);

// Split each row into an array
FileCCValuesRows=split(FileCCValuesString, LineSeparator);

// Create new arrays for the content of column and for each row
FileNameArray=newArray(FileCCValuesRows.length);
XValueArray=newArray(FileCCValuesRows.length);
YValueArray =newArray(FileCCValuesRows.length);


// Start of the loop going through the list of image files in the input folder selected above
for (Filei = 0; Filei < InputFileList.length; Filei++)
{
InputFileNamei=InputFileList[Filei];
InputFilePathi = InputDirPath+InputFileNamei;
if(endsWith(InputFilePathi, ".tif"))
{
open(InputFilePathi);

//////////This is where I am stuck
//////////Get the XValue and Value from the CSV file for the row in which
//////////FileName=InputFileNamei

run("Translate...", "x=XValue y=YValue interpolation=None");
}//end if
}//end for File i loop

// Notice of end of process
waitForUser("Process is done");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add another `for` loop (after opening the current image) that goes through all lines and checks if the line starts with the current image name and then split the current line to get the x and y values:

```bs
for (i=0; i < FileCCValuesRows.length; i++) {
    if (startsWith(FileCCValuesRows[i], InputFileNamei)) {
        values = split(FileCCValuesRows[i], CellSeparator);
        xValue = parseInt(values[1]);
        yValue = parseInt(values[2]);
        run("Translate...", "x=" + xValue+ " y=" + yValue + " interpolation=None");
    }
}
```

Note that the "ImageJ" way of doing it would be to open your CSV file in a *Results* table and use the [`getResultString`](http://imagej.net/developer/macro/functions.html#getResultString) and [`getResult`](http://imagej.net/developer/macro/functions.html#getResult) macro functions to get the required values. Here's a version of your macro using these:

```bs
// Make a pop up to select the input directory
InputDirPath=getDirectory("Select Input directory");

// Get the list of files in the input input directory selected above as an array
InputFileList=getFileList(InputDirPath);

// open the csv file in a Results table
FileCCValuesPath=File.openDialog("Select the file containing the coordinates");
open(FileCCValuesPath);

// Start of the loop going through the list of image files in the input folder selected above
for (Filei = 0; Filei < InputFileList.length; Filei++)
{
    InputFileNamei=InputFileList[Filei];
    InputFilePathi = InputDirPath+InputFileNamei;
    if(endsWith(InputFilePathi, ".tif"))
        {
        open(InputFilePathi);

        for (i=0; i < nResults; i++) {
            if (getResultString("FileName", i) == InputFileNamei) {
                xValue = getResult("XValue", i);
                yValue = getResult("YValue", i);
                run("Translate...", "x=" + xValue+ " y=" + yValue + " interpolation=None");
            }
        }
    }//end if
}//end for File i loop

// Notice of end of process
waitForUser("Process is done");
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, IamgeJ does not handle array higher than 1 dimension excepted if we open them in a result window?

Comment: What part of this code makes ImageJ know the csv file you open should be considered *the* Results table? Is it just assuming the csv file will be named "Results.csv"? What if this is not the case?

Comment: @NathanStutzman the `open()` function will open csv or xls files into _the_ singleton results table, and all subsequent calls will work on this table. You can work with several tables and rename them using the Table.* macro functions that were mostly introduced after the time of the above post.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for your replies
This is what I end up doing:

1-Split the array by row using

```bs
FileValuesRows=split(FileValuesString, LineSeparator);
```

2- Create new array for each column (I removed one line because of the header)

```bs
Column1Array=newArray(FileValuesRows.length-1);
Column2Array=newArray(FileValuesRows.length-1);
```

3- Create a for loop that screen each row and break it into each individual column (Starting at 1 because of the header)

```bs
for (Rowi=1;Rowi<FileCCValuesRows.length; Rowi++){
  FileCCValuesRowi=split(FileCCValuesRows[Rowi], CellSeparator);
  //Array.show(FileCCValuesRowi);
```

4- Add the content content of each row into the previously created array (-1 because of the header)

```bs
  Column1Array[Rowi-1]=FileCCValuesRowi[0];
  Column2Array[Rowi-1]=FileCCValuesRowi[1];
}
//end if for Rowi
```

5- In the next step the aim is to find the row number corresponding to current open image. This is done in two steps:
5.1- Screen the csv file for the number of occurrence of the string (in this case the filename)
5.2 if occurrence is non null add them to an Indices Array
5.3 Use this indice to get the value corresponding to that row in the array created before

```bs
//Returns the indices at which a value occurs within an array 
Occurence=0; 
// Screen the FileName Array row by row and count the number of occurence
for (Rowi=0; Rowi<lengthOf(FileNameArray); Rowi++) { 
    if (FileNameArray[Rowi]==InputFileName) { 
        Occurence++; 
        //print(Occurence);
    } //end of if 
} // end of for Rowi

// If found
if (Occurence>0) { 

    // Create an array of length the number of occurence
    IndicesArray=newArray(Occurence); 
    Occurence=0; 

    // Screen the FileName Array row by row and add the row of occurence into the Indices Array
    for (Rowi=0; Rowi<lengthOf(FileNameArray); Rowi++) { 
        if (FileNameArray[Rowi]==InputFileName) { 
            IndicesArray[Occurence]=Rowi; 
            Occurence++; 
        } 
    } 


    //Array.show(IndicesArray); 
}
```

Final step

```bs
//Get the X and Y translation value for the File being processed
In this case I have only 1 occurrence so I will take the first line of the Indice array which is the line 0

XValue=Column1Array[(IndicesArray[0])];
YValue=Column2Array[IndicesArray[0]];


//Translate the picture
run("Translate...", "x=XValue y=YValue interpolation=None");
```

Comment: Great! As noted in my answer, using ImageJ's own *Results table* would have saved you from populating the column arrays manually, so you could have omitted steps 2, 3 and 4.